# OpenGL ES 2.0 Equivalent for ES 1.0 Circles Using GL_POINT_SMOOTH?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, geometry

OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't have the GL_POINT_SMOOTH definition which ES 1.0 does. This means code I was using to draw circles no longer works:

```
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glPointSize(radius*2);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,nPoints);
```

Is there an equivalent in ES 2.0, perhaps something to go in the vertex shader, or must I use polygons for each circle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL ES 2.0 with iPhone: GL_POINT_SMOOTH draws squares with ES 2.0 but works in ES 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234379/opengl-es-2-0-with-iphone-gl-point-smooth-draws-squares-with-es-2-0-but-works-in)

Comment: @Kornel The answer to that question involves OpenGL ES 1.0, not ES 2.0 .

Comment: still, don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use point sprites to emulate this. Just enable point sprites and you get a special variable `gl_PointCoord` that you can read in the fragment shader. This gives you the coordinates of the fragment in the square of the current point. You can just use these to read a texture that contains a circle (pixels not in circle have color of 0) and then discard every fragment, whose texture value is 0:

```
if(texture2d(circle, gl_PointCoord).r < 0.1)
   discard;
```

**EDIT:** Or you can do it without a texture, by trading texture access latency for computational complexity and just evaluating the circle equation:

```
if(length(gl_PointCoord-vec2(0.5)) > 0.5)
    discard;
```

This might be further optimized by dropping the square root (used in the `length` function) and comparing against the squared radius:

```
vec2 pt = gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5);
if(pt.x*pt.x+pt.y*pt.y > 0.25)
    discard;
```

But maybe the builtin `length` function is even faster than this, being optimized for length computation and maybe implemented directly in hardware.

Comment: Sweet, thanks yet again Christian :) That's the last question for now!

Answer (score 0):

And answer is - yes, you must use polygons (e.g. textured quads) to get smooth points.